# How can one offer free ringtones on your web site?

Tags: hyperlink, mobile-phones

I've been asked to come up with options to offer free ringtone downloads on a website.  These would be *actual* free ringtone downloads, not "Sure, we've got free ringtones, but wouldn't you rather have these much cooler ringtones over here for $1.99?", but actual free-to-download ringtones.  Is there a way to provide this in a relatively global manner?  Is it as simple as providing a low-quality, 30-second MP3 that the user can convert themselves?  Is there a service out there that provides this functionality?  We're looking for options.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There's different methods of starting downloads based on which carrier/phone you're using

- Sprint - GCD(generic content descriptor)
- Verizon you have to send an MMS
- ATT - depends on the phone
- Nokia phones need a DD(download descriptor)
- The list goes on and on and on

Not really a simple problem to solve

Answer (score 0):

ringtones vary by phone; some require MIDI ringtone, for example, but for most modern phones a direct download of a short mp3 file is sufficient